# How To update Arraylist when clicking buttons in activity in background using service class

Tags: java, android, arraylist, service

I am developing an android driver tracking application, its gives information about driver status like he is in driving , sleeping or rest, for that i have one arraylist and using that arraylist i am plotting a step graph.

In my activity class i am placing 3 buttons when driver clicking on driving button 1 should add to the array list for every 30 seconds,when clicking on sleep button 2 should add to the same array list for every 30 second same as the third button clicking 3 should add to the array list for every 30 second. By using the array list values i am plotting graph in my view.its working fine when application is running live. but when i close the application also the values should add to the array list background for that i am trying to use service class. In service class the array list values should add automatically based on button clicked in activity class.and show that array list in activity to plot the graph.

The above same function is to be done using service class when clicking buttons in activity class.

How it is possible to update array list in background when changes(like button clicks) are done in activity class.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: When an activity is in background how on the earth you  can click the button?

Comment: Once activity is started, background service also should start and add the values to array list based on button click when changing the button click it automatically change values and add to array list.